# Javadoc link unformatted

Tags: hyperlink, formatting, javadoc

I came over this issue a few times now.
When I write javadocs there are times when I would have quite a lot of links. However, with respect to the javadoc style guide, I avoid to always use @link for multiple mentioned references but just use @code. Nice thing: Eclipse also gives me auto-completion with the @code tag.
Bad thing: When I now rename the reference - e.g. a method - all @link references will be updated, but the @code references will not.

What I am search for: Either a possibility for @link without highlighting the link or something like @code which will be updated by Eclipse when I do some refactoring.

Any hints on that?

Thanks,

Erik

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
{@linkplain ClassName}
```

this will be updated on refactoring changes, but it will displayed in the normal text font and not displayed in a code-font.